# Secondary IP on one interface (Debian 8)

Tags: linux, debian, networking

Im trying to add a secondary IP on an old Debian 8 server at work and have an issue. The setup look like this (just the IP parts in /etc/networking/interfaces):

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 10.10.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.0.1
```

When I restart the networking services everything seems to work as a charm and ifconfig shows everything as it should. Its also correct when i loook at the routing-table with "route -n".

The problem is that I cant access the server using the new IP. I cant ping it and I cant access it through http/https (its a webserver). Even Nutanix is showing that the server got two IPs.

Am I missing something or is this something that might have to be fixed in the firewall (not on the server)?

Comment: Are your router/firewall and ethernet switch configured to deliver the two different subnets (`192.168.0.0/24` and `10.10.0.0/24`) through the single ethernet cable to this server?

Comment: @SottoVoce Yes, its added on the interface/VLAN in the firewall. We have servers on both subnets in our Nutanix environment.

Comment: I guess it's time to use `tcpdump` to see if the packets are reaching the network interface.  Pinging from the machine to the 10.0.0.1 router works?  The router's MAC address for that address shows up in `arp -n -a` ?

Comment: There are too many unknowns here for us to help you. What do the route tables on your debian 8 server look like? What endpoint are you using to test access to the server? What network is it on? What does the interface configuration on that system look like? How about the route configuration? What does the network topology between the two systems look like? Consider including the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` for both systems involved.

Comment: multi-homing problem: from clients to this server's IP addresses the path is clear. The return path from this server to the *same* client should change depending on the IP address involved, but won't with your config. This requires policy routing. (btw: on Linux ifconfig and route are obsolete and insufficient to configure policy routing). Has to be fixed on the server because a firewall shouldn't allow and be able to work with asymmetric traffic.

Comment: So you mean if I connect to the server it will use the first IP:s route to get back to the client? When i ran "route -n" it seem right. I got it to work today, had to do some routing in our firewall.

Comment: For a system in a different LAN and routed in both cases by the same firewall/router it will use the first default route displayed to reply, for both IP addresses. Obviously that's the wrong choice for the IP related to the 2nd default route. Then specifically for UDP (rather than TCP) services hosted on it, if the UDP application is not multi-homed aware (IP_PKTINFO) and not configured adequately (never listen on 0.0.0.0) then it will *also* choose the wrong IP address to reply. This can't be fixed on the firewall/router. Despite the bandaid done on the firewall, the problem is on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **virtual interface**:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0 eth0.1
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.10.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.0.1
```

It will probably work on Debian 8, that I have no option to test. For Debian 11 I recommend to switch to use systemd-networkd, and stay away from old ifupdown.

Comment: How is that different from what’s shown in the question?